# An extra unknown parameter with an ajax request with dataType "script"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to add parameters from a form inputs into a rails `link_to` which responds with a `.js.erb`. (For clarity, I am not trying to submit the form.) The form looks like this:

```
form_tag players_path, method: 'get', id: 'my_form' do%>
  <%= number_field_tag :min_age, params[:min_age], id: 'min_age' %>
  <%= number_field_tag :max_age, params[:max_age], id: 'max_age' %>
  <%= submit_tag  'go'%>
<% end %>
```

The `link_to` looks like this:

```
<%= link_to '70 lbs & Under', players_path(:min_weight => 0, :max_weight => 70), id: 'my_link',  remote: true %>
```

what i am trying to do is to add the values of `#my_form` as parameters of `#my_link`. To do this i am using jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#my_link').click (function(){
    var parameterValues = $('#my_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        data: parameterValues,
        dataType:"script"
    });
    return false;

});
});
```

This adds the form input values to the `link_to` parameters but also adds an extra parameter `_` which i have no idea where it's coming from.
The generated request URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/players?min_weight=0&max_weight=70&utf8=%E2%9C%93&min_age=0&max_age=22&_=1379588007864
```

where is the last parameter `_=1379588007864` coming from? When i change the `dataType` to `JSON` in the ajax request, the parameter disappears. How can i get rid of this parameter and still use `dataType: "script"` in the ajax request?

Comment: I guess this is to avoid cached request, if you set option of ajax request `cache:true,` this extra param should disappear.

Comment: Thank you A. Wolff, that worked, just put this as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-cache param.

From the [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp') Type:
>   Boolean If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

So to get rid of this param, set as option of your ajax request `cache:true`

Comment: such a tough thing to search for, especially when you've been using the `.get` helper instead of `.ajax`. To disable it, i had to switch to `.ajax` and apply the settings update there